# Regex that matches strings that don't start or end with something

Tags: regex, regex-negation, swiftlint

I am trying to write a swift lint rule that will ignore certain files in my project. Those files either start with Fake or end with Spec.swift.

Example:

```
Object.swift  
FakeObject.swift  
ObjectSpec.swift
```

I only want the regex to match on `Object.swift`

Using http://rubular.com I was able to get it working with `^(?!Fake).*(?<!Spec).swift`

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work with swiftlint.

A regular expression that works for excluding files ending in Spec.swift
 (`.*(?<!Spec).swift`)doesn't work on http://nsregularexpression.com. So I'm not sure how swiftlint is doing it.

Comment: What is your goal? Testing out the nsregularexpression.com or use a regex in a Swift piece of code? If the latter, go and use your regex, `"^(?!Fake).*(?<!Spec)\\.swift$"`

Comment: My goal is to write a swiftlint rule that ignores files that start with Fake or end in Spec. None of these regular expressions work with swiftlint for this purpose.

Comment: After checking the Github code, I am afraid that side does not support lookarounds that are perfectly valid in ICU regex flavor that Swift supports.